# Tranparently configure an std::function / lambda callback

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have something like the following structure. It's a container which invokes a callback on all its elements. `fct` could be a lambda, a functor or a plain function pointer.

Now, in some cases I'd like to optionally configure `fct` before I call it. For example, `fct` computes a complicated function on each x. But `ContainerX` already knows an intermediate result - I would like to tell `fct` the intermediate result. If `fct` is a functor, it has a state and it can store the intermediate rsult. If it's a plain function, it can not store the intermediate result and should be called without the pre-configuration.

```
class ContainerX{
    void callback(function<void(X* x)> fct){
        // 1. Tell fct the intermediate result, if it is able to be configured
        // 2. Call fct for all x in the container
    }  
}
```

There are basically many ways to do this:

- I could define `fct` as `function<void(X* x, double result)>`
- I could define `fct` as an abstract class which has the actual function and a preconfiguration function.

But these solution require me to change the signature of `callback` in a way that I can no longer call it with plain functions as well as with functors.

Is there a way to transparently, optinally configure `fct`?

Comment: Let the functions have an optional parameter, that represents the intermediate result.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I was not aware of optional parameters in C++. Could you provide a short code snippet how this would look? (Particularly, the signature of `fct`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can no longer call it with plain functions as well as with functors."? What would be the problem with having an overload?

Comment: I think a good C++ way should be to use virtual methods instead of callback. I solved a lot of problem using C++ virtual methods.

Comment: What I meant with optional parameters are e.g. a pointer to the intermediate result, that is null if no intermediate result can be provided or something like `boost::optional`.

Comment: So the signature would look something like this: `void callback(function<void(X* x, T* intermediate)> fct)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But I think, my requirements can not be met. Clearly, there are many good and simple ways to do (almost) what I want, but there exists no solution for the specific question.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a true callback. Instead, you're trying to duplicate `std::for_each()`. If your container exposed `begin()` and `end()`, you could use `std::for_each` directly. This also hints at your second behavior - that appears to be a variant of `std::accumulate(begin,end,initial_state)`.

Comment: @Micheal Could you please explain which are the requirements that cannot be met (see my previous comment)? So that we can have a good shot at helping you:)?

Comment: You can not just insert a few lines of code at "1." without changing anything else in the code. This would be possible, if you would use `MyFunctor func` instead of `function<...> fct` as argument. But then you would no longer be able to pass a plain function.

Comment: But generally, I also think that the question originates from a somewhat wrong approach to iterating over a complicated, nested container. I'm currently redesigning this part.

Answer (score 3):

I would create an overload of `callback` does use the `result` parameter. It would look something like this:

```
class ContainerX{
    void callback(function<void(X* x)> fct){  
    }  
    void callback(function<void(X* x, double result)>){   
    }  
}
```

> But these solution require me to change the signature of callback in a way that I can no longer call it with plain functions as well as with functors.

There are in essence two different callback functions. One which takes a function  using an intermediate value. One that doesn't. Sometime you want different signatures which do roughly the same thing. That's what overloads are for:).